# Can I create a workflow for an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: 2013, workflow, office-web-apps

I have an Excel365 spreadsheet in my Sharepoint13 user account which I am sharing with everyone except external users. Everyone needs to update this sheet, so I would like to create a workflow for it. The workflow needs to send out emails to everyone, telling them to update the sheet. Then it needs to send me an email every time someone has updated the sheet.
Can this be done, or do workflows only apply to documents? ? If it can be done, how do I set it up?